# show popup based on mouse clicks count in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement, I want to display popup based on mouse click count. If user clicks mouse two times should display popup type-2, If user clicks mouse three times should display popup type-3. Is this possible with Jquery.

I have tried below code..

```
var mouseCount = 0;
$(".counterClick").click(function() {
    mouseCount += 1;
  
    if(mouseCount == 2){
      alert('display popup 2')
    }
    if(mouseCount == 3){
      alert('display popup 3')
    }
    
});
```

Main problem is, if user clicks two times, popup show popup type-2. but user clicks 3 times again shows type-2 popup. How can I solve this. Please suggest me.

Comment: you need to debounce user clicks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a time out to it that clears the click after some miliseconds.
Otherwise it will keep counting, that's why you can get 3 instead of 2 :D

```js
var mouseCount = 0,
    clearer;

$(".counterClick").click(function() { 
    mouseCount += 1;
    clearTimeout(clearer);

    clearer = setTimeout(function() {
        if (mouseCount === 2 || mouseCount === 3) {
           alert(mouseCount);
        }
      
        mouseCount = 0;
    }, 400); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="counterClick">Click</button>
```